# Bigquery write truncate in golang

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I'm working on a Golang application that interacts with a BigQuery table partitioned by a `TIMESTAMP` column named `invoice_month`. My goal is to insert and overwrite data within a specific partition. I believe utilizing the `WRITE_TRUNCATE` disposition is the correct approach for this task. However, I've encountered difficulty in specifying this disposition using the `Inserter()` method. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.